# Python xpath HTML scraping issue with dynamically-created webpage content

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I am a complete newbie to programming, so excuse me if I made any stupid mistakes. Below are my HTML parsing results,  having used Python and its xpath function. Unfortunately, I can't access precisely that part of the website in which I am interested (variables wiki3-wiki8 don't return an element, only the empty "[ ]"). The programme only pulls the list's first element, wiki2=*/div[1], but neither its child, wiki3=*/div[1]/a, nor any of its siblings, e.g. wiki4=*/div[2], all of which I need.

I think the problem may have to do with the fact that the website content I am trying to access is dynamically created, i.e. only the first 12 of the list's ~8000 elements are shown - additional elements only appear on screen if one scrolls down to the bottom of the page (a java script seems to be responsible for that, see wiki7 in the HTML Source Code).

The material below contains two parts - the first is the Python output of the programme, while the second shows that segment of the webpage's HTML body in which I am interested.

Python Script For HTML Parsing (currently only designed to see whether all parts of the website can be captured by xpath):

```
Python 3.5.1rc1 (v3.5.1rc1:948ef16a6951, Nov 22 2015, 23:41:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import html
>>> page=requests.get('http://www.wikifolio.com/de/Invest/SearchWikifolio#/?tags=aktde,akteur,aktusa,akthot,aktint,etf,fonds,anlagezert,hebel&media=true&private=true&assetmanager=true&theme=true&super=true&WithoutLeverageProductsOnly=true')
>>> tree=html.fromstring(page.content)
>>> wiki1=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]')

>>> wiki1
[<Element div at 0x5af6af1b88>]
>>> wiki2=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]')

>>> wiki2
[<Element div at 0x5af6af1ea8>]
>>> wiki3=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')

>>> wiki3
[]
>>> wiki4=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]')

>>> wiki4
[]
>>> wiki5=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[19]')

>>> wiki5
[]
>>> wiki6=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[37]')

>>> wiki6
[]
>>> wiki7=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/a')

>>> wiki7
[]
>>> wiki8=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/script[3]')

>>> wiki8
[]
>>> wiki9=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/script')

>>> wiki9
[<Element script at 0x5af6af1ef8>]
>>>
```

HTML Source Code (including manually added variable names in ** **):

```
**wiki1**   <div class="search-result-content js-search-result-container" style="">
**wiki2**       <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
            <div class="actions">
**wiki3**           <a href="/de/SG1979">
            <h6>
            <a href="/de/SG1979">DACH-Trading&Invest</a>
            </h6>
            <div class="wikifolio-bar">
            <div class="search-result-detail-info">
            <div class="search-result-wikifolio-tags">
            </div>
**wiki4**       <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
**wiki5**       <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        <div id="guiSearchParams" data-directmatchurl="" data-params="{"searchTerm":null,"orderBy":"topwikis","realMoneyInvestorsOnly":false,"savingPlanOnly":false,"leverageProductsOnly":false,"withoutLeverageProductsOnly":true,"showPrivateWikifolios":true,"showMediaWikifolios":true,"showAssetManagerWikifolios":true,"showThemeWikifolios":true,"showSuperWikifolios":true,"austrianLicenseOnly":false,"swissLicenseOnly":false,"tagFilters":["aktde","akteur","aktusa","akthot","aktint","etf","fonds","anlagezert","hebel"],"rankingFilters":{}}"></div>
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
        <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
**wiki6**       <div class="wikifolio_item" style="display: block;">
**wiki7**       <a id="loadMoreProjects" onclick="checkPositionBeforeLoading(); event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;" href="#">weitere Wikifolios anzeigen</a>
**wiki8**       <script type="text/javascript">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
**wiki9**   <script type="text/javascript">
```

Does anyone have an idea why this problem of only partially accessible website content exists and how I can circumvent it?

I promise eternal gratitude to the person that can help me out! Thanks :)

Comment: If parts of the page are generated by JS, you have to use tools that can execute the JS and deliver you the result. For example, you could look into Splash: https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! :)